# JotForm conflict with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jotform

I am trying to use JQuery datepicker along with Jotform in my html page.
but it seems that jquery and jotform dont get along after all .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.1.8.3.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jotform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If i eliminate first line of above code the jotform works fine and if i eliminate the second line and keep first line the datepicker will work fine. (Jotform is an online form builder)

There is a conflict record since 2011 but i cant find if that is solved or not.

```
  $(function() {

  //-----------------------------------
  // Show Picker
  $('#startDate').datepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true
  });
  //-----------------------------------
  // Show Picker
  $('#dueDate').datepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true
  });

 });
```

The following is part of the  section of my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jNotify.jquery.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jNotify.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jotform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax_load.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc-ar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc-fa.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="styles/jquery-ui-1.8.14.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Any tip and help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you try replacing '$' with 'jQuery' in your function to see any improvement? Do you have any js error output in the console?

Comment: Have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: @grotiri there is no error - i tried your solution . no effect

Comment: @TheBronx using that solution stops datepicker

Comment: @dave can you show us how have you used noConflict mode? You know have to stop using `$` and replace it with `jQuery`? And what does "stops datepicker" mean? See the console, what's the error?

Comment: to be honest i didnt know how to use noConflict(). i added jQuery.noConflict(); before the  $('#startDate').datepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true
  }); and inside the function

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is too large to explain in a comment:

#### Using jQuery noConflict mode

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

First, add the noConflict script after loading jQuery:

```
<!-- this is where you are loading jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="here/you/are/loading/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- and now lets enter in noConflict mode -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
</script>
```

This way the `$` function is "free" again so other lib can use it (the same name can't be used by two libraries, it's a global var so shit is going to happen).

Well, now on we won't be using `$` for jQuery. If you want to use jquery, the new magic word is `jQuery` (yeah, very original), for example:

```
jQuery("#menu").show();
```

So, if you have to use datepicker, just replace `$` with `jQuery`. For example:

```
jQuery('#startDate').datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true
});
```

Remember, the keyword `$` is no longer attached to jQuery. So you have to use `jQuery` everywhere. Or you can also use a new alias, for example if you think `jQuery` is too large:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
//and now we are going to use it:
j("#menu").show();
```

There are more examples here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: that didn't solve the problem. i finally used an other form builder. but thnx for nice tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Just use self calling anonymous function and pass jQuery and catch it as $ in your code such as :

```
 (function($){

  $(function() {

  //-----------------------------------
  // Show Picker
  $('#startDate').datepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true
  });
  //-----------------------------------
  // Show Picker
  $('#dueDate').datepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true
  });

});

})(jQuery);
```

and modify jquery script inclusion as such(same as TheBronx suggested):

```
<!-- this is where you are loading jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="here/you/are/loading/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- and now lets enter in noConflict mode -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
</script>
```

This is the only way that uses minimal code change. Thanks.